# Update with Inner join or subquery - multiple relations

Tags: sql-server, subquery, inner-join

I need and update on Table exp_pedcom on cases where a field of another table are null ( EXP_Procimp), but these two table do not have a direct relation to each other, so I actully need to "route" it though two other tables in order to relate them. The "routed! relation works, it returns as expected, but the update doesn't. I've tryed both as a direct inner join using from and as a subquery ( which is actually easier to demonstrate, so That's what goes here.

```
UPDATE EXP_PEDCOM
SET STATUS_ATENDIMENTO=0
WHERE EXP_PROCIMP.DAT_RECEBIMENTO IS NOT NULL IN (SELECT EXP_PROCIMP.DAT_RECEBIMENTO
FROM 
EXP_PEDCOM INNER JOIN 
EXP_INVOICE_IT ON EXP_PEDCOM.NUM_PEDCOM = EXP_INVOICE_IT.NUM_PEDCOM INNER JOIN 
EXP_INVOICE ON EXP_INVOICE_IT.COD_DOCUMENTO = EXP_INVOICE.COD_DOCUMENTO INNER JOIN 
EXP_PROCIMP ON EXP_INVOICE.NUM_PROCIMP = EXP_PROCIMP.NUM_PROCIMP)
```

Any tips?

Comment: Could you tell whether it's MSSQL, MySQL...?

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to use it using the `UPDATE... FROM...` syntax. (I messed with formatting and aliases while working out what the query actually did.)

```
UPDATE EXP_PEDCOM
 set STATUS_ATENDIMENTO = 0
 from EXP_PEDCOM
  inner join EXP_INVOICE_IT it
   on EXP_PEDCOM.NUM_PEDCOM = it.NUM_PEDCOM
  inner join EXP_INVOICE iv
   on it.COD_DOCUMENTO = iv.COD_DOCUMENTO
  inner join EXP_PROCIMP pr
   on iv.NUM_PROCIMP = pr.NUM_PROCIMP
 where pr.DAT_RECEBIMENTO is not null
```

This will work [*caveat: I could not run and so debug possible syntax glitches*], but it's hard to explain why/how this works. It's also a tad unconventional; hopefully you'll get other posts that show the "proper" way to run such queries.

Comment: beat me to it. That should work as is but two things to note based on OPs original statement: 1. While they wrote not null in the query they stated that it is when it is null in the question, a possibility for why the query has not worked. 2. If point 1 is true, this means that some values will not be updated when they should be, due to a possible requirement for an outer join.

Comment: Also this syntax wuill not work on every datbase backend which is why @T_G asked in teh comments above which db you are using, THe syntax for this is very differnt form database to database.

Comment: This is pretty much it. The one thing you should change is to use an alias for EXP_PECOM. Then you update the alias and not the base table. There are cases where you can inadvertently update rows outside of the query when you don't update the alias.

Comment: I did "not null" based on the part of the query that reads "...IS NOT NULL IN...", and missed the "is null" reference at the head of the post. As @KHeaney points out: if `NOT NULL` is the criteria, then the where clause changes to `is null`, and if not null due to the absence of a row is a valid criteria, then some or all of the joins would need to be made outer joins.

Comment: @HLGEM, the "sql-server" tag was present when I posted both my answer and this comment, and I went by the (mouseover) tag description: "Microsoft SQL Server is a relational database management system..." and assumed they were using Microsoft's RDBMS.

Comment: @Sean, yes, an alias can be used for EXP_PECOM. I have hit rare cases where the alias doesn't work, I suspect when the table is joined on itself, but I'm not 100% sure of that. As I could not test the code to be certain, I erred on the side of caution and didn't alias the "target" table.

Comment: @PhilipKelley the point I was making is that you should alias the target table and update the alias or you can update unexpected rows. I will find a reference explaining this.